# what is the script for implementing LAN in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I am trying to develop a LAN multi player  game using unity  game engine.
what is the code in c# for implementing it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not here to code for you.

Comment: Look on the unity asset store... Or even do a quick google search for some basic tutorials.

Comment: Better you can add in your question that what you have tried to develop a LAN multi player game instead of asking ' what is the code in c# for implementing it? '

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As mentioned by @Rob this is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 1):

[Unity 5.1](http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.1) introduced a new high-level networking module called UNET ([see blog post of announcement](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/12/announcing-unet-new-unity-multiplayer-technology/))

here is some documentation

- http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetOverview.html
- https://unity3d.com/services/multiplayer

here are some Unite Talks on Youtube

- [Lucas Meijer on Unity Multiplayer, VR and Unity Roadmap - Unite Europe 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUEreuxmBj0)
- [Democratizing Multiplayer Development - Unite 2015 (Boston)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Vk-EXpVELs)